# Get my own attribute's data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

I use jQuery to build dynamically a . Because I need to catch later the double-click events on the table's cells, and I need to know exactly which row and column were (double) clicked, I set my own attribute on each of the rows and on each column, i.e.:

```
<tr data-tr-number="2">
    <td data-td-number="1">John</td>
    <td data-td-number="2">Due</td>
    <td data-td-number="3">U.S.A.</td>
</tr>
```

Now, when I try later to get the values of these attributes (and also the html value of the element), I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Thnx

```
this.attr("data-td-number")   --->   Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

same for:

```
this.html    or     this.closest("tr").attr("data-tr-number")
```

Comment: 'this' is a tricky concept in JavaScript. What is the scope you are trying to access the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `this` points to the [HTMLTableCellElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) object, not jQuery instance object. So you can't use `attr` method on it. Instead use:

```
$(this).attr("data-td-number")
```

You can verify it easily:

```
console.log(this instanceof HTMLTableCellElement); // true
console.log($(this) instanceof jQuery); // true
```

You can always wrap pure HTML element into jQuery function to construct new instance of the jQuery with all necessary methods like `attr`, `closest`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

or you can just do this.

```
$(this).data("td-number")
```